# -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError Multiple heap dump creation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

`"-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp"` This parameter will help to take heap dump automatically when server limit is reached.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/clopts-139448.html#gbzrr

I can see detailed information on above link but, "**OutOfMemoryError**" message prints so many times in my server log times.

So, If the error msg occurs multiple times, will JVM take multiple heap dump ?

Regards,
Peter

Answer (score 2):

The oracle jvm creates a heap dump only on the first OOM when this flag is specified. However you can manually create multiple heapdumps if the jvm process is still alive and responsive. A little bit of googling:
[-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError not creating hprof file in OOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518839/xxheapdumponoutofmemoryerror-not-creating-hprof-file-in-oom)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the JVM. I think the Oracle JVM only dumps once.